# takeoff doesn't respond in ar drone with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ar.drone

I was trying the steps given on the link http://www.instructables.com/id/Autonomous-AR-Parrot-Drone-20-Flying/?ALLSTEPS to control the ar drone. However its getting connected with the drone but doesnt response anything for takeoff instruction

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var client  = arDrone.createClient();
client.takeoff();
```

I tried the step 8 to get the videofeed and its working.

So, what could be the reason for takeoff not to work (i tried with the smartphone application and it worked)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: When I was trying this with a windows machine it didnt work but when I tried it with ubuntu then it worked